# Do servers and deamons get restarted after a severe security update in debian?

Tags: debian, apt, security

Let's say I have an Apache HTTP server running on a debian server installation. The Apache apt package became a severe security update and I already installed the new package.
But the old buggy Apache HTTP process is still running.
Will it automatically get restarted so the fix is finally applied?

Answer (score 2):

It’s not clear from your question whether

> But the old buggy Apache HTTP process is still running.

is a hypothetical scenario, or something you actually noticed.

However, as a general rule, when Debian packages providing services are upgraded (or reinstalled), the daemon managed by the service is restarted once the package is fully installed and configured. So after an `apt upgrade` operation involving the Apache HTTP server, you should see that the daemon was restarted. You can see this implemented in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/apache2.postinst`, as part of the `configure` handling (search for “restart”).

See also [this Debian FAQ entry](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/pkgtools.en.html#updaterunning) and [the man page for `dh_installsystemd`](https://manpages.debian.org/debhelper/dh_installsystemd.1), which is the tool used to handle daemon setup in maintainer scripts for daemons managed by systemd units; these are configured to restart daemons on upgrade by default.

Note that this only covers services; other upgrades can require restarts, without those restarts being automatic. This includes the kernel (unless it’s upgraded by `unattended-upgrades`, and reboots are enabled), most libraries, and “end-user” applications. In some cases, even services can end up being only partially restarted — for example, `sshd` daemons managing specific connections won’t be restarted when the SSH service is restarted (so that the connections aren’t broken).

Comment: It's hypothetical. I mean the Apache httpd service. Good to know not all things get restarted automatically and I think I simply have to beware of it.